# How to setup Next Auth GoogleProvider with Next 13 App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to setup the authentication system for my NextJS 13 with Experimental App and src folder but I am not being able to fully setup the authentication since I am being redirected to the URL `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error` with error 404.

1. I have configured Google OAuth Credentials to get the `clientId` and `clientSecret` tokens and setted up the API auth to:

[image]

2. I have created a `ProvidersWrapper` component with the `Session Provider` from `next-auth/react` package:

```js
'use client'
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react'

export default function ProvidersWrapper({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <SessionProvider>
      {children}
    </SessionProvider>
  )
}
```

3. I have wrapped the `src/app/layout.tsx` `{children}` with the `ProvidersWrapper` component.
4. I have created the `src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts` file with the following code according to the [Next-Auth documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers):

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        })
    ],
})
```

> Note: I have tried hardcoding both credentials but I got the same error.

5. I added the button to the sign in page (I have tried also using `signIn()` without the `"google" value.`

```js
<button
    onClick={() => signIn("google")}
    className="bg-gradient-to-r-red-pink text-white p-2 rounded transform hover:scale-105 hover:shadow-lg transition duration-200 ease-in"
>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} className="mr-2" />
    Google
</button>
```

Whenever I click on the Sign In button I am redirected automatically to the `/api/auth/error` path.

So, what am I doing wrong here? or how this should be setted up properly?

Answer (score 4):

Well, thanks to Google Bard I got "the help" I was looking for.

1. In the 4th step I mentioned the path where `[...nextauth].ts` should be located but instead, I have changed it to a folder and an API route:

From: `/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`

To: `/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts`

2. In the `route.ts` file I modified the code as (according to the [Next Auth Route Handlers documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/initialization#route-handlers-app):

```js
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
        })
    ]
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```